# How to get two WAR files to run separetly on JBOSS 7

Tags: java, jboss, war, playframework-2.1

Ive been searching but unable to find an solution to the problem I have.

Description:
I have two WAR files stage.war and master.war that are essentially the same application but with different names. The war files are generated through the plugin https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin that I use to be able to develop using the play framework.

My goal is to have both of the WAR files deployed on JBOSS 7. But when I try to do this only one of the WAR files gets deployed while the other one fails.

Im using standalone.sh to start the server and then I use the /deployments folder in JBOSS to deploy the WAR files. So I basically drop the WAR files into the /deployments folder and only one succeeds to deploy.

Here is the server log of the failed deployment (stage.war.failed)

`{"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"stage.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"stage.war\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"stage.war\""}}}}`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: have you configured the apps to use different contexts? do you have any idea why should one fail when other one is deployed, as separate wars shouldn't impact each other in any way? there should be more informative error message in the logs as well.

Comment: There should be a reason earlier in the log.

Comment: Thanks, but I found the reason it wasn’t working. In the standalone.xml for JBoss I commented out the following subsystem section: <code>  urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0  </code>. There appeared to be some conflicts with the play->war plugin that I use to generate war files from the play framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the steps

1. Make 2 copies of your standalone folder. Give them distinct names - like stage1 and stage2.
2. Place the war files under the deployment directory.
3. Make the appropriate changes in the standalone.xml so that the ports do not conflict.  This can be easily achieved by specifying a `port-offset` in one of the `standalone.xml` under

   socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:100}">

   So one of the ports will be 8080 while the other is 8180
4. Next make separate start up scripts for the two standalone instances or run the standalone.sh specifying the arguments. I use a .bat file and start it using `cmd` prompt

   ```
    standalone.bat -Djboss.server.base.dir=../stage1 -  Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=c:\tools\jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\stage1\log\boot.log -Dlogging.configuration=c:\tools\jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\stage1\configuration\logging.properties
   ```

and similiarly for stage2

Hope this helps.

Comment: Following the same instruction gave me error of address already bound. What could be missing?

Comment: You need to run both Jboss instances with different ports like one running on 8080, other running on 9080 - just an example

Comment: @amitsalyan How can I restart the server? For example stage1.